# Avoiding php-fpm logs being split by newline

Tags: logging, containers

We have a PHP server that is running in a container. The logging for PHP-FPM is done by writing to stderr and then kubernetes is forwarding those messages to the appropriate place.

We have some error log messages that have a \n newline character in them.

The result of that is that the error log message is split by new line, with each part being considered a separate log entry, and are also presented in reverse order.

Is there any sensible way of configuring PHP + kuberenetes to have log messages make it through as single entries?

Comment: How do you determine what is a single log entry?

Comment: From the contents of the call to the PHP function `\error_log($foo);` Whatever the contents of $foo are, that's a single entry.

Comment: The problem with that is, PHP itself distinguishes them by newlines.